# I am using org.bytedeco.javacv.{FFmpegFrameGrabber, Java2DFrameConverter} for converting .avi video to .jpeg exception attached in image

Tags: scala, ffmpeg

```
 val converter = new Java2DFrameConverter
`def extractAVI(rawDrivePath: String): List[String] = {
    var errorList: List[String] = List.empty
    FileUtils.listFiles(new File(rawDrivePath), new SuffixFileFilter(".avi"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
      .asScala.toList.foreach(aviFile => {
      var grabber: FFmpegFrameGrabber = null
      var aviStream: InputStream = null
      var isFailedExtraction: Boolean = false
      try {
        LOGGER.info(s"--------inside try----------${aviFile.getAbsolutePath} {}",aviFile.length())
        aviStream = new FileInputStream(aviFile.getAbsolutePath)
        LOGGER.info("--------create grabber----------{}",aviStream!= null)
        grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(aviStream)
        LOGGER.info("--------created grabber extraction of drives----------{}",grabber)
        try {
          grabber.start()
        }
        catch{
          case z: Throwable =>LOGGER.error("Exceptions found in grabber start {}",z.getStackTrace)
        }
    LOGGER.info("--------start grabber of drives----------")
    var count: Int = 1
    for (frame <- Iterator.continually(grabber.grabImage()).takeWhile(_ != null)) {
      ImageIO.write(converter.convert(frame), "jpg", new File(aviFile.getParent, "capture-" + count + ".jpg"))
      count += 1
    }
    grabber.stop()
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      //LOGGER.info(s"Error while extracting images for ${aviFile.getAbsolutePath} {}", ex)
      errorList :+= s"${aviFile.getAbsolutePath.replace(rawDrivePath, "")} -> ${ex.getMessage}"
      isFailedExtraction = true
      LOGGER.info("last inside catch")
    }
  } finally {
    // Close the video file
    LOGGER.info("inside finally ")
    if (grabber != null)
      grabber.release()
    if (aviStream != null)
      aviStream.close()
    if (aviFile.exists() && !isFailedExtraction) {
      LOGGER.debug(s"Deleting ${aviFile.getAbsolutePath}")
      FileUtils.deleteQuietly(aviFile)
    }
  }
}
```

enter image description here

in this image, I am getting an error when I am going to start grabber.start()
on my local, it's working absolute fine at the time sonar-scanner test case run throws an exception which is attached in image.

### ERROR: comes when i star a grabber(grabber.start() in code )

## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000000000dc56, pid=447, tid=0x00007f45200a3b10 Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.io.EOFException at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2960) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1540) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) at

Comment: @Tim can u help me

Comment: Don't really know enough about the libraries, I'm afraid. You are getting an `EOFException` which implies that the file has invalid data, but not clear why this is generating a fatal exception. Could it be happening in another call to `grabber` that is not within a `try/catch`? Maybe wrap the whole thing in a `Try`